# How do I change my username?

Tags: installation

My first name is Lluis but always Ubuntu changes my name as Llus when my computer starts as Ubuntu. I don't understand why this 'i' is missed.

Comment: Maybe you typed your username wrong during the account  creation at your system?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the name that appears at startup, go to System Settings -> User Accounts.

Click the "Unlock" button at the top right of that box. Then click the name to the right, and retype it.

This won't affect your shell/system username at all, only your display name; if you were looking to change the system username too you will need to do something more along the lines of the other answer... though personally I would say it'd be safer to just make a new account and start over in that case; there could be (non-system) files elsewhere that reference your old username in some fashion or other, and these won't necessarily be updated with your new username if you do change it.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
# Become root
sudo -i
```

Next, as root, run:

```
usermod -d /home/new -m old

sed -i -e 's_old_new_g' /etc/passwd

sed -i -e 's_old_new_g' /etc/group

sed -i -e 's_old_new_g' /etc/shadow
```

Where "old" is your old user name ( Llus ) and "new" is the name you want ( Lluis ).

Log out and back in and you should be good to go.

**Note: You might want to use all lower case letters for  your user name (lluis) , up to you, see discussion in comments for details.**

Comment: Should point out the name should be lower case here

Comment: @GM-Script-Writer-62850 Why ? Upper case user names will work.

Comment: I think it's for similar legacy reasons to the rule of "username not longer than 8 characters". I don't think it's necessarily a requirement now, but could perhaps cause some compatibility issues with some things.

Comment: In fact, if you try and manually create a new user account containing a capital letter, you get an error message and have to use a "--force-badname" option. (doesn't happen if it's simply long). So yes, all lowercase is safer.

Comment: OK, I've not seen that error. The system identifies users by number not name.

Comment: That all seems like a really long risky way to do `sudo usermod -d /home/newuser -m -l newuser olduser` and `sudo groupmod -n oldgroup newgroup`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen the installer for ubuntu will now let you use upper case so I am assuming, you can have upper for your full name but not your name in a terminal

Comment: The commands I posted are tried and true

Comment: @GM-Script-Writer-62850: Capitals are fine in the full name, yes. The UI automatically creates a username based on what you type as a full name. You can see this in action if you try to add a user in the User Accounts menu: the username mimics what you type for "full name", except that spaces are filtered out and uppercase is automatically converted to lowercase. If you try to manually put an uppercase letter into the username, you get the error I mentioned above.