# Changing Username

Tags: 13.04, users

I tried to change my username using command:

```
sudo usermod -l newusername oldusername
```

so when I entered it in terminal it showed me:

```
user 'myusername' is currently used by the process 2553
```

What does it mean?

Comment: IMO you should change user names in recovery mode, the error message you got I am guessing is because you are logged in.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen That's an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change user names in recovery mode, the error message you got I am guessing is because you are logged in and running processes as the user you want to change.

Comment: can u please tell me the steps for changing username in recovery mode?

Comment: The commands are as given in the link listed with the closure note. http://askubuntu.com/questions/310219/changing-name-in-this-os

Comment: i tried but it still shows:- user 'myusername' is currently used by process 2580.

Comment: no i tried it in terminal.

Comment: run those commands in recovery mode.

Comment: I ran those commands in recovery mode nuthing happened so i rebooted my system tried to login into my account my password was messed up.I was'nt able to login into my account. I successfully changed my password in recovery mode after that but, still having problem in changing username.

Comment: Hard to say, I would assume a typo, check the files you changed and your /home directory.

Comment: the user is not in sudoers file dammit! what do to now?

Comment: Boot to recovery mode and make sure you user is a member of either the sudo group or admin group, depends on the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: i dont know wat to do. please help me out