# Change username without loggin

Tags: username

In order to change username it is necesary to be not logged in.

**Question**

How can I start linux without log in? Even if I start in recovery mode it appears that the user is started.

I have tried in recovery mode but get:

```
usermod: user username is currently used by process 645
```

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/310219/how-do-i-change-my-username/310230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be best to create a temporary user to log in with in order to change your original user name. See this post for specific details:

[How do I change my username?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username#34075)

Comment: thanks. but that answer doesn't say anything about create a temporary user, isn't it?

Comment: @George I thought it didn't. Although I changed it in a different way, logged in as root. But the post was really useful. Thanks!